# Disable radio button depending on date

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I'm a novice in Javascript, and trying to figure out how to using Javascript to disable radio button attribute

In my form, I have a date picker and 10 radio buttons below. I want some radio buttons turn to gray if specific date is selected, and some another radio buttons turn gray if another date is chosen.

It's a bit complicated for me, so please help me.

Thank you very much

Comment: We need to see some code you already wrote

Comment: function gray() {
  var date = $('date_1');
  if (date.value = "24/12/2010") {
   for (var i=0; i<document.elements.length; i++) {
    if (document.elements[i].name == "radio0") {
      document.elements[i].disabled = true;
    }
   }
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

For learning something new, I suggest trying to solve the same kind of problem in a simpler situation.  Try making a form with just a textfield, and 2 radio buttons, and one of them is disabled when text is entered.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `date.value = "24/12/2010"` - it can significantly differ depending on user locale. Use new Date(date.value) to operate with Date type.